# Check if Variable is declared in a page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, error-handling

I have some web pages that include other pages, and I need to check if a variable (a string) has been declared in the page or not.

I was exploring try catch and finally, but im always getting a compiler error saying the variable doesnt exits.

syntax in my head is:

```
if variable(exists) then
do something
else
do nothing
end if
```

From what im finding is this wont even compile if the variable wasnt defined anywhere.  I kinda knew that, I was just hoping to find some kind of work around.  :/

Comment: do you mean declared in VB.net or declared in the web page as in a javascript variable?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  VB is statically typed at compile time.  If the variable doesn't exist in the scope in which you're using it, the compiler will tell you (and it sounds like it is).  What, exactly, is the problem?  (Your question implies that it's related to an earlier question.  Should you just edit that question to add context, or is this a new one?  If this is new and not a duplicate of the original, we'll need the context here as well.)

Comment: Site is built with includes for the header etc.  On a specific part of a site I have ONE VARIABLE defined so I can load the page dynamically through SQL.  In my header which is on every page, I want to update something dynamically if that variable exists.  Simple enough if I could grasp this one problem.

Comment: @Anthem - Don't use includes with asp.net. It's just an all around bad idea. Use Master Pages and Build custom controls and user controls instead. If this is classic asp rather than asp.net, please re-tag your question with the `asp-classic` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to use reflection...
This will not work for variables defined within subs/functions...

```
Friend Function VariableExists(ByVal variableName As String) As Boolean
  For Each tField As FieldInfo In Me.GetType.GetFields
    If tField.Name.ToLower() = variableName.ToLower() Then
      Return True
    End If
  Next
  Return False
End Function
```

Cose here is untested and may contain minor errors.  Think of it more like pseudocode.

Comment: Having said that... you claim that the variable is a page-level variable and defined via an include file... so YOU ALREADY KNOW if the variable is defined or not, neh?  Unless the file is included only if some condition/s are met...

Comment: Yeah I would know, problem is/was the script doesnt.

Comment: Well this should let your script know then.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring a variable, how about adding a simple Interface that you can use in the pages that need to be processed a specific way, then you can test whether or not the page implements the Interface?

For example:

```
Public Interface IMySpecialInterface
End Interface
```

In the pages that you want special behavior for:

```
Public Page MySpecialPage
  Implements IMySpecialInterface
End Page
```

In the code that processes the pages:

```
If TypeOf Me.Page Is IMySpecialInterface Then
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using an interface:

```
Public Interface ISpecialProp
    Property SpecialProp() As String
End Interface
```

Then you can test, if a class implements the interface or not using this code:

```
Dim spec = TryCast(obj, ISpecialProp)
If spec IsNot Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine(spec.SpecialProp)
End If
```